# Animated 'X' icon for bootstrap toggle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to animate the horizontal lines in the navbar to an 'X' when the page is reduced in size.

My navbar code is as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Company</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="certification.html">Certification</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="downloads.html">Download PDF</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="products.html">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="inquiry.html">Inquiry</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="events.html">Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

When I attempt to use the CSS shown [here](http://julienmelissas.com/animated-x-icon-for-the-bootstrap-navbar-toggle/) it does not work. Is there something I need to modify for my navbar specifically? I also notice that when I add the css, the :

```
 &:hover {
    background: transparent !important;
  }
```

the closing curly brace does not recognize the opening one. What am i missing?

Comment: You need to adjust your HTML so it's like the example you posted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because the tutorial is using [Less](http://lesscss.org/), a CSS pre-processor, extending the CSS language.

However, you just have to use the compiled CSS, and make a few changes.

In your html, add some classes to the bars in order to distinguish each of them :

```
<span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
```

Also, init your button with the class `collapsed`, or it will first render as a 'X'.

Then add the CSS compiled :

```
.navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 22px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.navbar-toggle .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}
.navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
```

And now it should work like a charm.

Here's a JsFiddle : [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gndkmc5y/)

Comment: Would you know why the "X" seems off by me? Like the two bars don't meet at their center.

Comment: Why is it working only with width 22px? I changed to 16px, and finding hard to cross those two lines...!!

Comment: @Micky, You have to translate the line as you rotate by roughly 1/2 the difference between the width of the hamburger minus the width of the X, and the lines must move out vertically by about the 1/2 height of the X minus the height of the hamburger icon.

See my explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64265878/5671180

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me

### Theory

CSS provides all the necessary animation tools. Basically what's happening is this:

- The top and bottom lines must rotate to form the X
- The middle line must disappear

The X will be taller an more narrow than the hamburger lines, so:

- The top and middle lines must move out vertically and to the right to maintain its center

### Application

```css
/* Define the shape and color of the hamburger lines */
.navbar-toggler span {
    display: block;
    background-color: #4f4f4f;
    height: 3px;
    width: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    transform-origin: center left;
}


/* top line needs a little padding */
.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 0.3em;
}

/**
 * Animate collapse into X.
 */

/* top line rotates 45 degrees clockwise and moves up and in a bit to close the center of the X in the center of the button */
.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translate(15%, -33%) rotate(45deg);
}
/* center line goes transparent */
.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}
/* bottom line rotates 45 degrees counter clockwise, in, and down a bit to close the center of the X in the center of the button  */
.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(15%, 33%) rotate(-45deg) ;
}


/**
 * Animate collapse open into hamburger menu
 */

/* top line moves back to initial position and rotates back to 0 degrees */
.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(0deg) ;
}
/* middle line goes back to regular color and opacity */
.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 1;
}
/* bottom line goes back to initial position and rotates back to 0 degrees */
.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(0deg) ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Bootstrap Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-toggler collapsed border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
            <span> </span>
            <span> </span>
            <span> </span>
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">
            Brand
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
<main class="container">
    <h1>Content Here</h1>
    <p>Shrink the viewport if to expose the hamburger menu.</p>
</main>
```

### What makes it work

Specifically, since the top and bottom lines rotate by 45 degrees to form the X, their center lines take up 70% of the width, so they must move in by 15%. This can be calculated using pythagorean theorem.

[image: Right angle dimensions]

As it happens, our hamburger menu is 26x21 px, or 24% wider than it is tall, but the X ends up being 20x20 square when you move the lines into place and you take into account the height of the lines (here defined as 3px).

In this particular implementation, we are defining the point of rotation of each line as being the center-left. This affects how much we move the lines up, since the lines are about 3px tall, they each add about (2.1/2)=1.05px to the height of the X, or about 33% of the height of the X.

Therefore 33% is how much they must move out vertically out so the two lines meet at the center of the X and form a 20x20px square.

[image: The lines must move like this]

### Customizing

The X will always make a square, so to find out how much to move them by, you just need to know the width and height of your `<span>` bars and the height of the resulting hamburger icon.

Plug those numbers into this equation:

[image: Equation]

Or in code:

```js
const line_width = 26; // px
const line_height = 3; // px
const hamburger_height = 21; // px

const x_width = x_height = 0.8 * line_width;
const line_move_y_percent = 100 * (line_width - x_width) / (2 * line_height)
const line_move_right_percent = 100 * (x_height - hamburger_height) / (2 * line_height)
```

Comment: Upvoted for a great in-depth answer, but I'm confused as to why jQuery is being sourced if "CSS provides all the necessary animation tools".

Comment: @hashimAziz I only included jQuery because Bootstrap likes it, probably for its dropdown and alerts. It's unrelated to the code demo.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to adopt [Adonis' excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64265878/1191147) (go and upvote) to work on one of Bootstrap 5's [navbar examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/navbars/#) with some notable changes:

- With Bootstrap 5's existing `navbar-toggler-icon` span, there only needs to be two extra spans for the icon bars, not three
- The button needs to have the `collapsed` class in order to avoid initialising as an X instead of the menu
- Made the animation a bit faster

With those changes in mind, here is the reflected markup for an animated hamburger menu animation in Bootstrap 5:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light collapsed" aria-label="Eighth navbar example">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand me-6 me-xl-7" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="navbarsExample07" aria-controls="navbarsExample07" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-home">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item mx-sm-1 mx-lg-2 mx-xl-3">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mx-sm-1 mx-lg-2 mx-xl-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Find My Car</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mx-sm-1 mx-lg-2 mx-xl-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mx-sm-1 mx-lg-2 mx-xl-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mx-sm-1 mx-lg-2 mx-xl-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
.navbar-toggler span {
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 3px;
    width: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transform-origin: center left;
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 0.3em;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translate(15%, -33%) rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(15%, 33%) rotate(-45deg) ;
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(0deg) ;
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(0deg) ;
}
```

Comment: show.. it worked for me, bootstrap 5.0

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 26px;
  height: 2px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

**This should do it, if not just try to adjust the width value in the range of 20px-26px.**

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers above, my adaptation for Bootstrap 5.1. Working with booth
collapse & offcanvas. I used jQuery, but is not required.

Button:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
  <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
let $btn = $('.navbar-toggler');
$($btn.data('bs-target')).on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse show.bs.offcanvas hide.bs.offcanvas', function(){
    $btn.toggleClass('opened');
});
```

Css:

```
.navbar-toggler {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-toggler:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-toggler span {
    display: block;
    background-color: #4f4f4f;
    height: 3px;
    width: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transform-origin: left center;
}
.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 0.3em;
}
.navbar-toggler:not(.opened) span:nth-child(1){
    transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(0deg) ;
}
.navbar-toggler:not(.opened) span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-toggler:not(.opened) span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(0deg) ;
}
.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translate(15%, -33%) rotate(45deg);
}
.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}
.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(15%, 33%) rotate(-45deg) ;
}
```